# Nim compiler optimization flags

Tags: compiler-optimization, nim-lang

Let's say I am compiling my code with `nim c -d:release myprog.nim`. How can I see what flags are being passed to `gcc`, and how to specify additional flags? For example I want to use `-ffast-math`.

I tried to trace the logic in `/etc/nim.cfg`, but I'd rather be able to see directly what `nim c` is emitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `--listCmd` (from the [Compiler User Guide](https://nim-lang.org/docs/nimc.html), Advanced Flags section) will *show* the flags being passed to your C compiler.

To pass flags to the C compiler directly the Nim Compiler User Guide has this to say:

```
-t, --passC:OPTION  pass an option to the C compiler
-l, --passL:OPTION  pass an option to the linker
```

I haven't tried these myself but they seem like they should work.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on a Mac and there are some annoying default flags being passed to clang, namely -lrt is breaking things, but where do I remove that?